# Session timeout upon refresh at login page

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml, session-timeout

I made a really simple *login and session* structure for reuse in my future JSP based applications. It's like this:

**web.xml** (the 1 minute timeout is to test my problem):

```
<session-config>
 <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<filter>
 <filter-name>Access</filter-name>
 <filter-class>com.app.Access</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>Access</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.app.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Access.java** filter:

```
// Check if the page's the login or if the user logged, else asks login
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    boolean logged = httpRequest.getSession(false) != null && httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user") != null;
    if (httpRequest.getServletPath().equals("/login") || logged)
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    else
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/login");
}
```

**Login.java** servlet (authentication shortened for test):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid())
        request.setAttribute("failure", "session timeout");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", null);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", new User());
    response.sendRedirect("");
}
```

And the **login.jsp** page, at the root of WebContent, has a `<form action="login" method="post">` form with appropriated innerHTML for authentication and a **${failure}** field to receive a *session timeout* or a *login failed* message.

This structure works perfectly for me. It intercepts, asks for login, checks both session and authentication, etc., but there's a small flaw: **if you're at the login page and refresh it (either F5 or pressing Enter at the URL) after the timeout, the page receives and shows the "session timeout" message in ${failure}.**

I found no real working way yet to make it know that the previous page was the login page. Tried about five different ways without success, including `request.getHeader("Referer")` and the `lastWish` tag library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to let your publicly accessible JSPs (such as the login page) to **not** create the session at all. Requesting a JSP page namely implicitly creates the session by default. This can be achieved by adding the following line to top of JSP:

```
<%@page session="false" %>
```

This way `request.getRequestedSessionId()` will return `null` and thus the timeout check will be bypassed. The session will this way then only be created when you actually login the user. I'd only remove the following line from the servlet since that makes no sense and would still create the session:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", null);
```

Comment: I didn't know something like that could be done! I added that to reset the user in case he got to the login page manually, but with your solution I prefer to remove that. Thank you very much, BalusC!

Comment: @Trevor: Nice edge case. Usually, in the average self-respected website, an already logged-in user would not see any "login" link (as that's confusing in UX perspective) and any attempt to visit it by forcing the URL or following a link/bookmark would result in a redirect to the main page, maybe with a "You're already logged in" message. For that redirect, a filter could be used (maybe the very same authentication filter which you're probably already using).

Comment: Nice tips, I'll work on implementing that too in my structure. By the way, I swear I had marked the answer, sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

I Just do it like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    String servletPath = httpReq.getServletPath();
    HttpSession session = httpReq.getSession();
    String redirectUrl = "/login.jsp";
    if (
            (servletPath.endsWith("login.jsp")) ||
            (servletPath.endsWith("rss.html")) ||
            (servletPath.endsWith("httperror403.html")) ||
            (servletPath.endsWith("httperror500.html")) ||
            (servletPath.endsWith("imageMark.do"))||
            (servletPath.indexOf("/api.do") != -1) ||
            (servletPath.indexOf("/help/") != -1)){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }  else if (session == null) {
        httpReq.getRequestDispatcher(redirectUrl).forward(request, response);
    } else {
        SystemUser user = (SystemUser)session.getAttribute("user");
        if (user == null){
            if (session != null){
                session.invalidate();
            }
            httpReq.getRequestDispatcher(redirectUrl).forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this answer OP's concrete question? By the way, there's a logic flaw in your code. The `session` is **never** `null` in this construct.