# How to prevent login page alone from session expiry in JSF

Tags: session, jsf, authentication, timeout, session-timeout

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Enter url and go to Login Page
2. Leave the tab upto Session Expiry Limit.
3. After the Limit crossed try to Login.

Actual Result
Session Expired

Expected Result
Session expiry should not be applied for Login page.

The following code explains the session timeout limit

**Web.xml**

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I agree the session expiry functionality is working fine for other pages of the web application. But how to prevent the login page from this SESSION_EXPIRY in jsf.

Comment: What do you mean? Prevent the login page from session expiry?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Which problem exactly are you trying to solve? That the enduser faces a `ViewExpiredException` when submitting any form in the login page? Or something different? Are you sure it isn't already covered by http://stackoverflow.com/q/3642919?

Comment: @BalusC Its not covered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored

But it is the exact same as the following question in JSF context

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278913/session-timeout-upon-refresh-at-login-page

Comment: Also not stateless views? Then I absolutely don't understand your concrete problem anymore. Please edit question and clarify in proper technical terms.

Comment: As per your edit: OK, this confirms the initial guess as described in my first comment. Now, please tell how exactly stateless views doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @BalusC: I hope the latest update in the Question can help. The application uses Single view